# "local" to somewhere else

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for something "**local**", "**focused**", "**centred**" **elsewhere**?

Let's assume "local" means "an area close to a location usual to someone".

What would be the word for **"here" for a far person**?

In other words, I'm looking for a morpheme like "**far-local**".

Samples:

- "The <foo> disaster went global, affecting the local machinery."
- "The computer updated the local state using a <foo> state."

<foo>: the word I'm looking for

Please forgive in advance my irritating rigor. I already thought about these cases, which I would like to skirt if possible:

- "far": to what I ask, it *is too loosely coupled to "local"*
- "global": to what I ask, it *refers to a too broad area*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite of *local* that seems to fit your intended uses is *remote*.

From [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/remote?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic), these definitions can apply:

> 1. far apart; far distant in space; situated at some distance away:
> 2. distant in relationship or connection:

Comment: *Remote* is not the sole opposite of *local*, as *global* could also be. It depends on the perspective you take.

Comment: I clarified that this is the opposite that seems to fit his use.

Answer (score 0):

"Local to /name of area/" might be what you're looking for in general.

But, to avoid re-writing your first given sentence, try writing, "The /name of area/ disaster went global, affecting [our or /our town's name/'s] local machinery."

For the other one, if by "state" you mean New York, Texas, California, etc., I would go with something like "an alternative State", or "/name of State/ as an alternative."  If you mean "situation", I would go with the term "comparable area's state", or "comparable town's state".